# How to make your own native-like (copyable) controls with ATL/WTL?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, atl, wtl

When you're using WTL, you can freely copy controls that represent **built-in** objects:

```
// Notice that CWindow is passed by _copy_, because it only wraps the HWND
int OnNotifyFormat(CWindow wndFrom, int nCommand) { ... }
```

Now, if I want to make my **own** controls, it's easy enough to say:

```
template <class T, class TBase = CWindow, class TWinTraits = CControlWinTraits>
struct CMyControlImpl: public CWindowImpl<T, TBase, TWinTraits>
{
    std::vector<int> internal_info;

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(...)
        ...
    END_MSG_MAP()
};

struct CMyControl : public CMyControlImpl<CMyControl>
{
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS_EX(TEXT("MyControl"), 0, COLOR_WINDOW)
};
```

but now the problem is that I **can't** simply say:

```
void OnFooHappened(CMyControl control)
{
}
```

because `CMyControl` is more than just a handle -- it contains the data itself!

What is the correct way to make a control class that is **consistent** with the built-in ATL/WTL classes, with respect to this copy behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few custom controls right there in WTL, in `\Include\atlctrlx.h`:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Classes in this file:
//
// CBitmapButtonImpl<T, TBase, TWinTraits>
// CBitmapButton
// CCheckListViewCtrlImpl<T, TBase, TWinTraits>
// CCheckListViewCtrl
// CHyperLinkImpl<T, TBase, TWinTraits>
// CHyperLink
```

Apart from this, you will find custom WTL controls made right way at [http://viksoe.dk](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/all_wtl.htm).

The "copiability" of the controls is based on the fact that standard controls are available to you via handle `HWND`, and you can easily copy, attach, detach etc. this handle, and while it is valid the whole control is good. Wrapper classes are thin and only have the `HWND` member variable in them.

Custom controls on the other hand as you noticed have additional information, and you cannot copy them as easily. You can still have this additional information allocated/released dynamically with the control, you will implement the additional control specific window messages and notifications, and then you can create a thin wrapper class that converts methods into messages, sends them to the real control, which in turn will handle them, esp. by converting messages with parameters back to real methods. This let you copy thin wrapper class, but the control itself is way more complicated and cumbersome (you don't normally need to have it that way).

Comment: Wow, interesting, I didn't notice that. So the "custom" built-in controls don't work that way either?! (e.g. I don't see a constructor of `CBitmapButton` taking in `HWND`; it seems to be holding all the info itself.)

Comment: Yes WTL controls are holding the info with the class. Yet they are relatively simple. As I said, it is possible to do it the way you wanted, and it is not the easiest way. If you are deriving your custom control from standard control, you might also find it useful to create base window/control (such as with dialog template), and then in your code initialize your custom control with subclassing existing original control window. This is a cool way of having your control with templates in resources.